# How does Liquibase cross instance command

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-sql

I want to ask whether liquibase supports cross instances, between instances can be connected if possible, is the command correct like this
.....\liquibase --changeLogFile=filename.sql update liquibase.command.url mysql://aws.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/databasename

Answer (score 0):

No, not in one command. For the user to run Liquibase on multiple instances, they will have to run the command several times to each instance with the correct URL values.

Here is an example you can use to create a loop that will run the update (or other Liquibase commands) to connect to different endpoints.

- https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-toolbox/tree/master/project_examples/multi_catalog_example